# How to store credentials for Azure VM RDP

Tags: azure, rdp

When I connect to my Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2) via RDP, I check the "Remember my credentials" checkbox in the connection dialog. After that, I connect to the VM fine, do some work there and disconnect.

However, when I next start the same RDP connection, I need to enter the password again - it doesn't remember it. I don't have this behavior on other, non-Azure VMs / RDP connection. Can I configure something so that Azure RDP remembers the password? Why is it not remembering it in the first place?

Comment: Did you tried to save your settings in a RDP file ? In this case, does it perform the same way ?

Also, what is the exact message you get when you try to log on to an Azure VM ?

Anyway, you can use Microsoft RDCMan available at the link below to group and persist your connection settings

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced an issue with group policy not enabling the use of saved credentials. You can check this article for details on how to change your group policy to enable RDC to use saved credentials.

http://blog.ronnypot.nl/?p=247

tldr;
Run => CMD => gpedit => Local Computer Policy => Computer Configuration => Administrative Templates => System => Credentials Delegation

Enable all of the settings pertaining to allowing credentials, add "TERMSRV/*" to your server list for each setting.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to edit the Azure RDP file and enable credential saving.

1. Right click RDP file -> Edit
2. Uncheck checkbox next to 'Always ask for credentials'
3. Save connection settings